# backbone-relational id references with backbone.marionette

Tags: backbone-relational, marionette

I use backbone-relational's includeInJSON: 'id' to only include related model ids to avoid spamming my server-side with the whole object tree. Unfortunately, Backbone.Marionette.View by default exposes only the attributes of the view mode as returned by toJSON, which means related models are no longer accessible in view templates.

I realize I need a custom Marionette.View serializeData. As this will be needed for nearly all my models, I'm hoping to solve this generically; i.e. override serializeData for all views such that it does the right thing with backbone-relational id references.

Any chance someone's already done this? I'm not too hopeful of that, but figure there are others that could use this, so if nothing else this will serve as a place to dump my solution once I've coded it. :)

Any solution will require one of these options:

1. Define two versions of toJSON for models, one which uses includeInJSON and the other which always treats it as true.
2. Some way to punch a hole through Marionette's restriction on view templates only using model attributes and attribute-based helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a functional solution using option #1, but it's such a hack I can't bear to post it publicly. Basically, in serializeData I'm reaching into the model and modifying _relations before and after a call to  toJSON. Not thread safe and ugly as heck. Hoping to come back soon and find a proper solution.

Comment: Given that there are no threads in Javascript, I wouldn't worry too much about it being "not thread safe."

Comment: Ah, right. Well, the ugly bit stands and still bugs me, but until you reminded me just now, I forgot this hack was in my code. Guess that means it's doing it's job and staying out of the way. :)